# Histogram bin size(matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm creating a histogram(which is NOT normalized) using matplotlib.
I want to get the exact size of each bin. That is, not the width but the length. 
In other words, number of data contained in each bin.
Any tips???

Comment: that is one of the things that histogram returns  `bin_vals, bin_edges, patchs = np.hist(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Use the numpy function `histogram`, which returns arrays with the bin locations and sizes.